# How to use boost::call_once() on a function with arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to use boost::call_once() to achieve a thread-safe lazy-construction 
singleton scenario, however, the base singleton class has many derived classes thus the getInstance() function takes an argument to determine which derived class to initialize. The code looks like,

```
Singleton * Singleton::getInstance(Input * a) {
if (!instance) {
    instance = buildme(a);  //buildme() will return a derived class type based on input a.
    }
return instance;
}
```

I want to use `boost::call_once()`, but looks like it can only be used on functions with no arguments `void (*func)()`. If anybody knows about an alternative solution here please help.

Thanks.

EDIT::

Another question, how to call a non-static member function using `call_once`? I have a non-static `init()` member function of this class, but I couldn't find a correct syntax for calling it using `boost::call_once()`. Or should I make `init()` and everything used in it static?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind additional function parameters to a functor object using `boost::bind`.  Like this:

```
Input* input = ???;
boost::call_once(flag, boost::bind(&Singleton::getInstance, input));
```

You can use `boost::bind` to call non-static member functions as well, by passing the instance of the class on which you want to call the function to `boost::bind`.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   void func(int) { /* do something */}
};

Foo f;
boost::call_once(flag, boost::bind(&foo::func, &f, 10));
```

With C++11, you can use `std::bind`, here's another example. `boost::bind` is quite similar.

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(int x)
{
   std::cout << "f(" << x << ")\n";
}

void g(int x, const std::string& y)
{
   std::cout << "g(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n";
}


int main()
{
   auto ten = std::bind(&f, 10);
   auto example = std::bind(&g, 20, "Twenty");

   ten();
   example();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually std::call_once in C++11 accepts any number of arguments (after the once flag and callable) which are perfectly forwarded to the callable so std::bind is not needed for that case.

Comment: Thank you both. Chad's example is very helpful that now I know about the usage of bind. Also thanks a lot @John5342 for letting me know this useful information.

Comment: @Walter It was my hope that it might be incorporated into Chad's answer. I like votes but a single complete answer is even better. I have now added the C++11 stuff as a new answer though (with examples etc) per your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Chad, another quick question, how to use boost::call_once on non-static member function? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

C++11 contains an implementation of call_once (inspired by the equivalent Boost.Threads facility). It uses variadic templates and perfect forwarding to take an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <string>

void only_called_once(int i, std::string const & str) {
  // We only get here once.                                                                                                                                                         
}

void call_free() {
  static std::once_flag once;
  std::call_once(once, only_called_once, 42, "The answer");
}
```

You can pass an arbitrary number of arguments after the callable and they will all be perfectly forwarded (including r-value/l-value, const, volatile, etc).

This also works for member functions. You just have to pass a pointer to an object (convertible to the type the member function belongs to) as the first argument after the callable.

```
struct bar {
public:
  void only_call_once(int i, std::string const & str);
};

void call_member() {
  static std::once_flag once;
  bar instance;
  std::call_once(once, &bar::only_call_once, &instance, 42, "The answer");
}
```

If you are stuck with Boost then you can use `boost::bind` for the same purpose as has already been explained in another answer. Member functions with `boost::bind` work the same way as above by passing a member function pointer and an instance as the following parameter.